# How to get list of all the groups of particular attribute set using Soap API?

Tags: soap

My question is similar to this post :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952325/magento-retrieve-a-list-of-groups-from-a-attribute-set but there is no answer so.

I have attribute set id - 4 - Default Attribute Set. I want the list of groups created in Default Attribute Set using Soap API.

I checked the API documentation but it seems we can add, remove & rename only.

Basically what I want is to remove the group but for that I need to have already created group's ID so how can I get that using SOAP API?

Thanks.

Comment: I got the location of attribute group id & I removed the unwanted groups like this : `$client->call($session,'product_attribute_set.groupRemove',array($attribute_id));` but still the question exists that how would I know that particular group (id) is existing in magento or not byt SOAP API.

Thanks

Comment: Default Magento not provided this SOAP API method.

Comment: If you wand then create new custom method

Comment: Thanks Abdul umm, ok so I will search how to create custom method for this & how to call it through API :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow `steps` for the create new custom SOAP API method

**Step : 1** Create file `app/etc/modules/AR_CustomApi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AR_CustomApi>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </AR_CustomApi>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step : 2** Create file `app/code/local/AR/CustomApi/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AR_CustomApi>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </AR_CustomApi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
        <customapi>
                <class>AR_CustomApi_Model</class>
            </customapi>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_attribute_set_api>AR_CustomApi_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api</product_attribute_set_api>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step : 3** Create file `app/code/local/AR/CustomApi/Model/Product/Attribute/Set/Api.php`

```
<?php

class AR_CustomApi_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api
{
    /**
     * Retrieve attribute groups
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function groupList($attributeSetId)
    {

        // check if attribute set with requested id exists
        /** @var $attributeSet Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set */
        $attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($attributeSetId);
        if (!$attributeSet->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('invalid_attribute_set_id');
        }

        $groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSet->getId())
            ->setSortOrder()
            ->load();

        $result = array();
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $result[] = array(
                'group_id' =>$group->getAttributeGroupId(),
                'name'   => $group->getAttributeGroupName(),
            );

        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Step : 4** Create file `app/code/local/AR/CustomApi/etc/api.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <catalog_product_attribute_set translate="title" module="catalog">
                <methods>
                    <groupList translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <title>Retrieve groups from attribute set</title>
                        <acl>catalog/product/attribute/set/group_list</acl>
                    </groupList>
                </methods>
            </catalog_product_attribute_set>
        </resources>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <product translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <attribute translate="title" module="catalog">
                            <set translate="title" module="catalog">
                                <group_list translate="title" module="catalog">
                                    <title>Groups list</title>
                                </group_list>
                            </set>
                        </attribute>
                    </product>
                </catalog>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

**Step : 5** Create file `app/code/local/AR/CustomApi/etc/wsdl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                    schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="group_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntityArray">
                <complexContent>
                    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntity[]"/>
                    </restriction>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListResponse">
        <part name="result" type="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntityArray"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupList">
            <documentation>Retrieve product attribute groups</documentation>
            <input message="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListRequest"/>
            <output message="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupList">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded"
                           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded"
                           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**Step : 6** Create file `app/code/local/AR/CustomApi/etc/wsi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
             targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:complexType name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="group_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntityArray">
                <xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="complexObjectArray" type="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupEntity" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListRequestParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListResponseParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupList">
            <wsdl:documentation>Retrieve product attribute set groups</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="typens:catalogProductAttributeSetGroupListResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="catalogProductAttributeSetGroupList">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Step : 7**

- Go admin side `System -> Cache Management` and refresh all cache
- Go admin side `System -> Web Services -> Roles` and save all roles again

**Step : 8** Called custom method like

```
try {
    $attributeSetId =  4;
    $client = new SoapClient('http://magento.com/test/index.php/api/?wsdl'); // api url
    $sessionId = $client->login('ar123', 'ar123'); // API user name & key 
    $result = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product_attribute_set.groupList',$attributeSetId);
   echo "<pre>";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Oh my god this is awesome :)

Thanks Abdul for helping :)

Really great one :)

Comment: @Abdul how can i get sales order with each products of order, how can i get by API.

Comment: @zus Have you get all orders by API right?

Comment: @Abdul yes, right?

Comment: @zus Pls see here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html

Comment: yes, i know,  but i am new bie,, ,may i know how can i use API for this.